# When will this sequence have the following limit?

Tags: combinatorics

For the sequence $a_0, a_1,...$ we have: $a_n = 4a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2}, a_0= 1, a_1=x$. How should we choose $x$ in order to make the sequence's limit $-\infty$, if $n \rightarrow \infty$?

My idea:

I tried to solve this sequence as a recursion:

$x^2=4x-4 \rightarrow x^2-4x+4=0$

Our solutions are: both $x_1 = x_2 = 2.$

I am stuck at this point, how should I solve the recursion if both of the solutions are the same? I can't make my two geometric sequence independent. Any help with the task? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both solutions are equal to $2$, then it makes sense to use some “variation of the constant” method to solve the equation: namely, write
$$ a_n = c_n \cdot 2^n,$$
then the equation on the sequence $(c_n)$ is
$$ c_0 = 1, c_1 = x/2, \quad c_{n+2} = 2 c_{n+1} - c_{n}.$$
This last equation is satisfied by constant sequences, but also by linear sequences $c_n = A n$; it is actually the “second derivative” of $c_n$:
$$ c_{n+2} - 2 c_{n+1} + c_n = (c_{n+2} - c_{n+1}) - (c_{n+1} - c_n).$$
This means that you may write your sequence $c_n$ as $c_n = A n + B$,
or $a_n = (A n + B) 2^n$.

This is actually general: if $\rho$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial with multiplicity $d$, then the sequences $(A_0 + \dots + A_{d-1} n^{d-1}) \rho^n$ are solutions of the recurrence relation.

Now that you have the formula above, solving for $A$ and $B$ as functions of $x$ and finding the answer to your problem should be much simpler!